# Is it correct? $ p(a,c|b) = p(a|c)p(c|b) $

Tags: distributions, conditional-probability, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

I read two different papers on some similar problems. In one of the papers this statement is written:

$ p(a|b) = \sum_{c \in C}p(a,c|b) $

While in the other it is written as:

$ p(a|b) = \sum_{c \in C}p(a|c)p(c|b) $

Therefore, this expression should hold:

$ p(a,c|b) = p(a|c)p(c|b) $

I tried to prove it but failed at some point. 
Are they the same? Or am I missing something? Or maybe each of them are correct under a specific assumption?

Comment: second line should read $p(a,c|b) = \sum p(a|c,b)p(c|b)$ right?

Comment: @bdeonovic Yes it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the second article they should actually write:
$$ p(a|b) = \sum_{c\in C} p(a|c,b) p(c|b) $$
(unless $p(a|c)=p(a|c,b)$ for all $b$).

The equation $p(a,c|b)=p(a|c,b)p(c|b)$ is correct.

By definition,
$$p(x|y)=N(x,y)/N(y) = p(x, y) / p(y)$$
where $N(x,y)$ is the number of cases when both $x$ and $y$ hold, while $N(y)$ is the number of cases when $y$ holds.

Therefore,
$$ p(a,c|b) = N(a,c,b)/N(b) $$
$$ p(a|c,b) = N(a,c,b)/N(c,b) $$
$$ p(c|b) = N(c,b)/N(b) $$

We can easily see that the equation is correct.

Comment: I read somewhere this statement: $p(a|c,b)=p(a|c)$ under the assumption that $a$ is conditionally independent of $b$ given $c$. Does it make any sense to you in this example? It might have been their assumption.

Comment: By definition, $p(a|b) = p(a,b)/p(b)$. If a and b independent, $p(a,b) = p(a)p(b)$, hence $p(a|b) =p(a)$. Condition on $c$, you get what you want...

Comment: "I read somewhere this statement: p(a|c,b)=p(a|c) under the assumption that a is conditionally independent of b given c." Yes, you are right, the statement is true.

Comment: In the second article it is written that we write this marginalization based on the independence assumption of $c$ and $b$. In that case $p(c|b)$ will be $p(c)$ and makes the whole statement wrong. Am I right?

Comment: @dv_bn Could you please give me an example?

Comment: If we only know that $c$ and $b$ are independent, the equality $p(a|c,b)=p(a|c)$ may or may not hold.

Comment: By definition, $p(a|b,c)=p(a,b|c)/p(b|c)$. If $a$ and $b$ independent conditionally on $c$, $p(a,b|c)=p(a|c)p(b|c)$, hence $p(a|b,c)=p(a|c)p(a|b,c)=p(a|c)$.

Comment: @user31264 Back to the question: If we know that $c$ and $b$ are independent this statement: $p(a|b)=\sum_{c \in C}p(a|c)p(c|b)$ will be simplified to: $p(a|b)=\sum_{c \in C}p(a|c)p(c)$, right? And does the fact that the authors did not do this simplification make it a wrong statement?

Comment: "Back to the question: If we know that c and b are independent this statement: $p(a|b)=\sum_{c∈C}p(a|c)p(c|b)$ will be simplified to: $p(a|b)=\sum_{c∈C}p(a|c)p(c)$, right?" - No, we don't know if it is right or not.  PS: I mean, we don't know if the statement $p(a|b)=\sum_{c∈C}p(a|c)p(c|b)$ is correct.

Comment: @user31264 I copy from the article: "Formally, given $C$, we rewrite the expression of P(a|b) with the fair assumption of independence between the c and b."
It does not make sense to me.

Comment: It does not make sense to me either.

Answer (score 2):

Start from the identity $P(a,c) = P(a|c)P(c)$.

Now condition both sides with respect to $b$ and obtain

$P(a,c|b) = P(a|c,b)P(c|b)$